# получить значение тега <input> JS

Tags: javascript

Привет.

Как ни странно, но не получается получить значение тега `<input>`.

```js
var getNum = document.getElementById('get_num').value;
var addTime = document.getElementById('add');

addTime.addEventListener('click', getN);

function getN() {
  console.log(getNum);
}
```

```html
<div>
  Write time:
  <input type="text" id="get_num" name="get_num" value />
</div>
<div id="add" class="btn">Add</div>
<div id="total_time"></div>
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Потому что получать значение нужно **непосредственно** в обработчике.

Сейчас же ты выводишь то, что было сохранено при загрузке страницы.

```js
var addTime = document.getElementById('add');

addTime.addEventListener('click', getN);

function getN() {
  var getNum = document.getElementById('get_num').value;
  console.log(getNum);
}
```

```html
<div>
  Write time:
  <input type="text" id="get_num" name="get_num" value />
</div>
<div id="add" class="btn">Add</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает теперь!)